# Dynamic object property name in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value-coding

I'm trying to access a property of an object using a dynamic name... is this possible?

like in javascript:

```
var foo = 'bar';
appr.templates[foo];
```

the idea is to access `appr.templates.bar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `valueForKey:` for this purpose.

Like this:

```
NSString *foo = @"bar";

[appr.templates valueForKey: foo]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using Key-Value Coding or KVC, see the method `-valueForKeyPath:`. For example:

```
@interface Foo
@property(strong) NSString *bar;
@end

// Somewhere in other code, foo is an instance of Foo
NSString *bar = [foo valueForKeyPath:@"bar"];
```